# Google Places API: Error 400: (Bad Request)

Tags: java, android, google-places-api

I'm trying to create an android app that utilizes the Google Places API but I want it to list out a type of places that is currently not supported. I know I can add places via the app but I'm having an issue doing so. I keep getting the following error:

Error 400: (Bad Request)
Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request.

I've searched all over for working examples on submitting add requests to places api but I can't seem to find anything that could show me what I'm doing wrong. Below is the code I tried which for the most part I found on various sites and still can't seem to get it to work either:

```
private static final String PLACE_ADD_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/add/json?";

public PlacesList addPlace() throws Exception {

try {
        Log.v(LOG_KEY,"Adding Place...");
        GenericUrl reqUrl = new GenericUrl(PLACE_ADD_URL);
        reqUrl.put("key", API_KEY);
        Log.v(LOG_KEY, "Adding Place...");

        reqUrl.put("Host: maps.googleapis.com","{\"location\":{\"lat\":39.977112,\"lng\":-74.182799},\"accuracy\":50.0,\"name\":\"Artisan's Brewery & Italian Grill\",\"types\":[\"other\"],\"language\":\"en\":HTTP/1.1}");
        Log.v(LOG_KEY, "Requested URL= " + reqUrl);

        HttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = createRequestFactory(HTTP_TRANSPORT);
        HttpRequest request = httpRequestFactory.buildGetRequest(reqUrl);

        Log.v(LOG_KEY, request.execute().parseAsString());
        PlacesList place = request.execute().parseAs(PlacesList.class);

        Log.v(LOG_KEY, "STATUS = " + place.status);
        Log.v(LOG_KEY, "Place Added is = " + place);    

            return place;

    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        Log.v(LOG_KEY, e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        throw e;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you run this in the android emulator hoooked up to an HTTP proxy like fiddler, and see what you're sending over the wire?

Comment: No, I was running it directly from Samsung Galaxy Nexus. I'm hoping someone will have a tutorial or something on how to add places from within your application.

Comment: In lieu of that, try looking at the requests in an HTTP proxy, and see if you can manually tweak the request to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what ended up working for me.......

```
public JSONObject addPlace() throws Exception {

try {
       Log.v(LOG_KEY,"Adding Place...");
        String nameAdd = "NAME";  // Enter Place Name
        String typeAdd = "TYPE"; //Enter Place Type
        double lat = 00.0000; //Enter Place Latitude
        double lng = -00.00000; //Enter Place Longitude


       HttpPost post = new HttpPost(PLACE_ADD_URL);
       String postBody = 
               "{"+
                       "\"location\": {" +
                        "\"lat\": " + lat + "," +
                        "\"lng\": " + lng +
                       "}," + 
                       "\"accuracy\":50.0," +
                       "\"name\": \"" + nameAdd + "\"," +
                       "\"types\": [\"" + typeAdd + "\"]," +
                       "\"language\": \"en\" " +

                  "}";
       StringEntity se = new StringEntity(postBody, HTTP.UTF_8);
       post.setEntity(se);
       ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler=new BasicResponseHandler();
       String responseBody = new DefaultHttpClient().execute(post, responseHandler);
       JSONObject response = new JSONObject (responseBody);
       Log.v(LOG_KEY, "Request URL= " + PLACE_ADD_URL);


       return response;

    } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
        Log.v(LOG_KEY, e.getMessage());
        throw e;
    }

    catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        throw e;
    }
}
```